# how to fix touchpad ubuntu

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch

I have a `ZenBook UX363EA_UX363EA` with `Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS`.
I was developing an app for linux and I was implementing mouse and touchpad event handler.
since then I'm having issues with my touch pad and mouse cursor!
first of all I lost triple finger gesture functionallity and the mouse cursor fades out sometimes and I have to move mouse to top of the screen to see it again.
how can I reset touchpad ?

Comment: Which all changes did you make?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi 
if I did make any changes I did that by accident and I don't need it

Comment: We really cannot help much unless we get to know the changes you had made. There is no way to "restore" all the configurations (especially if you manually edit any configuration files). A workaround is to reinstall Ubuntu

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi all I did was detect cursor position or detect scroll offset using Compose Desktop framework.